# How to make a session for Auth in web2py?

Tags: session, web2py

The question pretty much says all. I have been looking at the web2py book where it says about session. But I just cant figure out how to use sessions from Auth table. I am trying to make a session for Email ID from the default Auth table where I can register and login.

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Can you be more precise about what you are trying to achieve? Do you just want to store the user's email address in the session? Anyway, web2py already includes a complete Auth system -- why can you not just use that?

Comment: Hi,
I am making a session, so I can have a text saying "Welcome %emailID%" when the user is logged on. I am using the auth system provided by Web2py but i dont know know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user is logged in, then the `db.auth_user` record is available in `auth.user` (assuming you have named your `Auth` object "auth"). So, in the layout view, you could have something like:

```
{{if auth.user:}}Welcome {{=auth.user.email}}{{pass}}
```

Note, the `auth.user` record is also stored in the session (so it doesn't have to be retrieved from the database on every request). So, `auth.user == session.auth.user`.

Comment: Hello. How do you access the email for a user who is logged out(forgot password but registered) to the view page?

Comment: If a user is not logged in, you don't know who they are, so presumably you cannot know the email address unless they provide it. Do your users log in with email addresses or usernames? If the latter and you have the username, you can always do a query to get the associated email address (`db(db.auth_user.username == username).select(db.auth_user.email).first().email`).

Comment: Thank you. In controller, I did: email = (db(db.auth_user.username==username).select(db.auth_user.email).first().email). But got this error: NameError: name 'username' is not defined

Comment: You would need to get the username from the user somehow.